# Repeat inside attribute with Angular

Tags: angularjs

I have a simple string array which represents classes:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.classes = ["one","two","three","four"];
}
```

I would like to bind these inside the class attribute of a single element as such:

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <div ng-repeat="class in classes" class="{{class}}"></div>
</div>
```

And render the following:

```
<div class="one two three four"></div>
```

I can't find a resource which explains how to do this. The code above generates:

```
<div class="one"></div>
```

How do I repeat INSIDE of the element with the `ng-repeat`?

http://jsfiddle.net/Lvc0u55v/788/

Comment: For this i might just create a function that takes in an array and returns a string. Intead of using ng-repeat

Comment: This one is not gonna be done using ng-repeat.. Ill give an anwser soon..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need `ng-repeat`, just `ng-class`, which accepts an array as input.

```
<div ng-class="classes"></div>
```

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass

Comment: Lots of solutions, this was by far the cleanest.